# Event-Sourcing definition

Tags: design-patterns, event-sourcing

Is "Event-Sourcing" a fancy name for a application that implements "Command Handler Pattern" that saves each command successfully executed (`SeatReserved`, `OrderCanceled`, `BlaBlaBlaDone`), only does inserts (no updates and no deletes, e.g: `Balance +100`, `Account Closed`) on the database and all selects are similar to `select top 1 MailAddress from UserAddressTable where UserID=@value order by lastUpdated desc` or `select sum(balance) from UserTransactions where UserId=@value`???

Comment: You could start at http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proposed definition of the *Command*-side is basically spot on.

However, no-one says that you'd have to store the events in a relational database. In fact, that's often a poor choice. When working with a simple bank account example, you may know in advance that you're going to need a *balance*, which means that you may maintain the up-to-date balance in a database table.

However, in systems removed from a normal bank account example, you may not realise in advance exactly how all the events are going to be interpreted.

That's why Event Sourcing is valuable. You never throw away data, so if, in the future, you realise that you'd like to perform a type of analysis you never predicted, you can, because you never deleted any data.

When you **interpret** the event stream, you often perform a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) of those events, producing an aggregate result. Sometimes, for efficiency reasons, you do it in advance, and then it's often called a *snapshot*.

Very closely related to Event Sourcing is the notion of [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Comment: I've been reading about CQRS too... considering it alot for my project... since ill be using only Azure table, current EF 6 goes out the window, and since ill have to write a persistence layer, i might as well use CQRS...

Answer (score 3):

Event sourcing is one thing, and CQRS is another thing.

**Event sourcing**, is basically persist all actions that your model(Akka actor) did in your system, in order to have a stateless model which is possible to give a state in time through rehydration of all those events.

```
(baskedtCreated, productAdded, productAdded, productRemoved,productAdded, baskedPayed)
```

So next time if I want to know what is the state of my previous basket, the system get an new instance of Basket, and the rehydrate with all the previous events, having a basket with final state payed.

**CQRS** is Command Query responsibility segregation, which basically it´s a architecture pattern to segregate your RestAPI in Commands for writing, and Queries for reading, giving you the chance to completely scale your servers separately.

`Let´s say 4 machines for Queries(Read always is more expensive), 1 for Commands?`

What people get confuse is, in the fact that CQRS is a pattern that works very nice with Event sourcing, since the `Command(CreateBasket)` works very nice commanding the `action-event(BasketCreated)`.

If somebody wants to introduce in the event sourcing world in scala, here I have a very nice open source project for it https://github.com/politrons/Scalaydrated

Answer (score 0):

Event-Sourcing is about rebuilding the state of your system using past events.

You do not persist commands (it is of course not forbidden to do so, but it has nothing to do with ES). You persist events. In your example SeatReserved, OrderCanceled, BlaBlaBlaDone are Events. You rebuild the state of your "Reservation-System" by reading and applying these Events instead of just reading the current state from a Database.

I think this is the most basic definition. Event Sourcing is often mentioned along with other things like CQRS etc. because it often makes sense to combine them.

If you want to learn about Event Sourcing and CQRS I recommend [this](https://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf) document by Greg Young who is often mentioned as the person who coined the term Event-Sourcing.

Also: I recommend NOT to read Matin Fowlers article on the topic. I would not dare to say that he is wrong... but the article might be at least confusing (especially the stuff about External Updates and other things). Note his disclaimer in the beginning that says: "I haven’t had time to work on them further".